# RoR: Error when connecting affilinet web services (logon function) using savon (ruby on rails) -> Deserialization Failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, deserialization, savon

I try to logon at the affilinet web services via the provided *logon* function. I'm working in a Rails 3 environment (3.0.x). I utilize the ruby on rails gem Savon in version 2 which in turn uses soap to connect to affilinet.
The most current wsdl can be found here https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl.
My code looks like this:

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl"
end
message = {'Username' => 'username', 'Password' => 'password', 'WebServiceType' => 'Publisher'}
response = client.call(:logon, :message => message)
```

The request generated by Savon:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tns="http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc" xmlns:ins3="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" xmlns:ins2="http://affilinet.framework.webservices/types" xmlns:ins1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF" xmlns:ins0="http://www.microsoft.com/practices/EnterpriseLibrary/2007/01/wcf/validation" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">  
  <env:Body>  
    <tns:LogonRequestMsg>  
      <tns:Password>password</tns:Password>  
      <tns:WebServiceType>Publisher</tns:WebServiceType>  
      <tns:Username>username</tns:Username>  
    </tns:LogonRequestMsg>  
  </env:Body>  
</env:Envelope>
```

When sending this request to the web service I get this (error) response:

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
      <s:Fault>
        <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/net/2005/12/windowscommunicationfoundation/dispatcher">a:DeserializationFailed</faultcode>
        <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The formatter threw an exception while trying to deserialize the message: There was an error while trying to deserialize parameter http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc:LogonRequestMsg. The InnerException message was 'Error in line 1 position 775. 'EndElement' 'LogonRequestMsg' from namespace 'http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc' is not expected. Expecting element 'Username | Password | WebServiceType'.'.  Please see InnerException for more details.</faultstring>
        <detail>
          <ExceptionDetail xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.ServiceModel" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
            <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
            <InnerException>
              <HelpLink i:nil="true"/>
            <InnerException i:nil="true"/>
            <Message>Error in line 1 position 775. 'EndElement' 'LogonRequestMsg' from namespace 'http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc' is not expected. Expecting element 'Username | Password | WebServiceType'.</Message>
            <StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerReadContext.ThrowRequiredMemberMissingException(XmlReaderDelegator xmlReader, Int32 memberIndex, Int32 requiredIndex, XmlDictionaryString[] memberNames)&#xD; ... (loads more) ...
            </StackTrace>
            <Type>System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.NetDispatcherFaultException</Type>
          </ExceptionDetail>
        </detail>
      </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Any ideas what's wrong?

EDIT:

The request in soapUI looks like this:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:svc="http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc" xmlns:typ="http://affilinet.framework.webservices/types">  

<soapenv:Header/>
<soapenv:Body>
  <svc:LogonRequestMsg>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <typ:Username>username</typ:Username>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <typ:Password>password</typ:Password>
     <typ:WebServiceType>Publisher</typ:WebServiceType>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <typ:DeveloperSettings>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <typ:SandboxPublisherID>?</typ:SandboxPublisherID>
     </typ:DeveloperSettings>
     <!--Optional:-->
     <typ:ApplicationSettings>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <typ:ApplicationID>?</typ:ApplicationID>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <typ:DeveloperID>?</typ:DeveloperID>
     </typ:ApplicationSettings>
  </svc:LogonRequestMsg>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Maybe the differences in the requests (generated by Savon and by soapUI) are the key!? Especially the different namespaces: svc/typ vs. env/tns. Any ideas? How can I tell Savon to use the svc namespace for the LogonRequestMsg?

Comment: To debug the SOAP layer I highly recommend to install SsoapUI (http://sourceforge.net/projects/soapui/files/). You can then test your SOAP messages to make sure *that* layer works. Then you can deal with Savon if that should be still necessary. The problem you describe is not (yet) related to Savon.

Answer (score 3):

Looking into the WSDL of Affili.net it shows that username, password, WebserviceType etc have the wrong namespace.

EDITED for the namespace after another look into your example. Username, Password and WebServiceType are defined in the namespace ins2="http://affilinet.framework.webservices/types" which is tagged by "ins2" in your case.

The quick and dirty way to get over it is

```
client = Savon.client do
  wsdl "https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl"
end
message = {'ins2:Username' => 'username',
           'ins2:Password' => 'password',
           'ins2:WebServiceType' => 'Publisher'}

response = client.call(:logon, :message => message)
```

Comment: Changing the namespace didn't help. soapUI says that the namespace of Username, Password and WebServiceType is 'typ': 
...
<typ:Username>username</typ:Username> <typ:Password>password</typ:Password> <typ:WebServiceType>Publisher</typ:WebServiceType>
...
but changing it to 'typ' doesn't help as well?! Is Savon really dealing the WSDL wrong?

Comment: For whatever reason Savon gives the namespace a different name than soapUI. If you look into the raw wsdl document then you find "tns:LogonRequest" as message type. I'm not the expert to interpret WSDLs. I take a pragmatic approach and debug what's coming from the server when I send my request. Savon gives you good logging to find it out. Have you tried to use my example with exact the same namespace prefixes in your environment?

Comment: I tried it exactly as you proposed but got the same error message which is the error message from the first post (see above). No clue what's meant by "'EndElement' 'LogonRequestMsg' from namespace 'http://affilinet.framework.webservices/Svc' is not expected. Expecting element 'Username | Password | WebServiceType'" in the error message. Those data is provided and the rest of the request is build by Savon according to the given WSDL. Apparently Savon is building a none compliant request, though.

Comment: found a difference in the way the message was created on my machine and on yours. I edited the Answer, please try again.

Comment: ins2 is "working". At least I get another error: "You have to enter a username that is not empty". Apparently the ins2:Username tag is correctly parsed but can't be interpreted. Is there an error in the API backend of the web services?

Comment: "You have to enter a username that is not empty": that's a funny error message.

Comment: I found out that the ins2 prefix is only necessary for the WebServiceType. The Username and the Password can be used without any prefix. Although affilinet is still saying that I have to enter a password that is not emtpy (a few hours ago it said that I have to enter a username that is not empty - doen't know why it changed from username to password?!).

Comment: I found that I had to use ins0 as the prefix and had to use it on Username, Password and WebServiceType. But this did solve it for me.

Answer (score 1):

i think the problem is with namespace order, after several request saw different order in namespace.

This code works for me (savod version 1), overwrite namespaces:

```
   message = { 
              'ins0:Username' => 'XXXXXXX',
              'ins0:Password' => 'XXXXXXX',
              'ins0:WebServiceType' => 'XXXXXX',
              :order!     => ['ins0:Username', 'ins0:Password', 'ins0:WebServiceType']
            }


  @client.wsdl.document = 'https://api.affili.net/V2.0/Logon.svc?wsdl'

  response = @client.request :logon do
    soap.body = message
    soap.namespaces["xmlns:ins0"] = "http://affilinet.framework.webservices/types"
    soap.namespaces["xmlns:ins1"] = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays"
    soap.namespaces["xmlns:ins2"] = "http://www.microsoft.com/practices/EnterpriseLibrary/2007/01/wcf/validation"
    soap.namespaces["xmlns:ins3"] = "http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Validation.Integration.WCF"
  end
```